# Optimize SQL-query in big database?

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

**Query**

```
SELECT *
FROM user_ip_tmp
WHERE too = 'http://example.com/'
AND contry != 'CN'
AND contry != 'TW'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 50
```

MySQL returns:

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 50 total, Query took 11.9276 sec) [id: 3452538 - 3448824]
```

if i remove 
     **ORDER BY id DESC**

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 50 total, Query took 0.0033 sec)
```

Explain  plan:
[image]

**count**

```
SELECT count( * )
FROM user_ip_tmp
```

[image]

Example of the database used

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_ip_tmp` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `dataip` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ref` text NOT NULL,
  `click` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `too` text NOT NULL,
  `checkopen` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `contry` text NOT NULL,
  `vOperation` text NOT NULL,
  `vBrowser` text NOT NULL,
  `iconOperation` text NOT NULL,
  `iconBrowser` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ip` (`dataip`),
  KEY `ip` (`checkopen`),
  KEY `ip` (`code`),
  KEY `ip` (`too`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5426268 ;
```

I want the correct way to do the query and optimize database for  **ORDER BY id DESC**

Answer (score 2):

It would be interesting to know something about the distribution of your data. Could you add the results of the following queries to your post? (no need for pictures, plain text will do).

```
SELECT count(*) FROM user_ip_tmp WHERE too = 'http://example.com/' AND contry != 'CN' AND contry != 'TW'; 

SELECT count(*) FROM user_ip_tmp WHERE too = 'http://example.com/';
```

Also, could you test this alternative for performance? **EDIT:** alias for subquery

```
SELECT sub.* FROM
(SELECT *
FROM user_ip_tmp
WHERE too = 'http://example.com/'
AND contry != 'CN'
AND contry != 'TW'
) sub
ORDER BY sub.id DESC
LIMIT 50
```

**Edit**  If it is an option to add and experiment with indexes, then you could try one of these (or both and see which is better)

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON `user_ip_tmp` (`too`, `id`);
CREATE INDEX index_name ON `user_ip_tmp` (`too`, `contry`, `id`);
```

Comment: SELECT count(*) FROM user_ip_tmp WHERE too = 'http://xxx.com/' AND contry != 'CN' AND contry != 'TW'; 

42171

SELECT count(*) FROM user_ip_tmp WHERE too = 'http://xxx.com/'; 

42879



`
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT *
FROM user_ip_tmp
WHERE too = 'http://xxx.com/'
AND contry != 'CN'
AND contry != 'TW'
)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 50

**no work Shows the problem**
`#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: yupp, I forgot to give an alias to the subquery I used in the from clause. I edited my answer and added it, thanks

Comment: Server stops working after it  CREATE INDEX index_name ON `user_ip_tmp` (`too`, `id`);
I think because there are more than 6 million entries and area of ​​base 1 GB

Comment: @10neencom, having a "text" field with no defined "length" is probably what is killing your server during create index.  I would index on say... left 200 or so characters of the "too" URL, then the ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index with:

```
 id, too and contry
```

Comment: I do not think will solve the problem
I think the problem in anything else
I do not know why when make ORDER BY id DESC 
Cause a rise in the query